# Do I need to use "--cleanDestinationDir" when building a Hugo site on Netlify?

Tags: hosting, web-hosting, netlify, hugo

I use `hugo --minify --cleanDestinationDir` when developing my site locally so I can be sure that everything I can browse to is as a result of the very last build.

Without `--cleanDestinationDir` content can remain available from a previous build.

Is it something I need to use when building a site on Netlify?

Comment: I can't hurt... but it is an interesting question.